# Strict inequality versus $\leq$ inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose that I know for a real number $x$, the following inequality holds
$$
-1\leq x\leq 1\tag{1}
$$
Why for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
-\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n}\tag{2}
$$
?

If I divide each sides of Inequality (1) by $n+2$, then I get
$$
-\frac{1}{n+2}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n+2}\tag{3}
$$
I also know that since $n+2>n$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n+2}<\frac{1}{n}
$$
So I can rewrite Inequality (3) as

$$
-\frac{1}{n}<-\frac{1}{n+2}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n+2}<\frac{1}{n}\tag{4}
$$
So now Inequality (4) can be written as

$$
-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{x}{n+2}<\frac{1}{n}
$$
which is different from Inequality (2)!

Comment: But it implies inequality (2), and therefore inequality (2) is true and its proof is complete.

Comment: Also, when you use words like "I can rewrite this as..." or "can be written as", there is an underlying meaning of logical equivalence, which is not what you want in all cases. Instead, what you have proved is that inequality (1) is equivalent to inequality (3) which implies inequality (4) which implies inequality (2) and you are done. In short: (1)$\iff$(3)$\implies$(4)$\implies$(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
-\frac{1}{n}<-\frac{1}{n+2}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n+2}<\frac{1}{n}\tag{4}
$$

implies

$$
-\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n}
$$

as well.

Though your proof illustrates that equality can't be attained.

It's like there is nothing wrong with writing $2 \le 10$ though we know that $2 < 10$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a< b$ is true, $a\le b$ is also true.

Answer (score 0):

$-1\leq x\leq 1$ is the same as saying that $|x|\leq 1$. Since $0<\frac{n}{n+2}<1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it follows that $$|x|\frac{n}{n+2}\leq 1\tag{1}$$

$(1)$ is the same as saying that $$-1\leq\frac{xn}{n+2}\leq 1$$ which again, dividing by $n$, is the same as $$-\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{x}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The steps that you have taken above are correct and in fact you have proved a stronger statement than was requested.

A final step to finish your answer would be

$$-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{x}{n+2}<\frac{1}{n}\tag{5}$$

Which implies

$$-\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{x}{n+2}\le\frac{1}{n}\tag{6}$$